# Добавление визуальных эффектов

Tags: html

На платформе лежит сайт, редактировать там особо ничего нельзя, но есть такой код на странице . вот не пойду как уменьшить размер отображаемых картинок в слайде. Уменьшал их в процентном соотношении, но они смещаются в левую часть и по центру расположить не получается. В интернете искал, экспериментировал, но нужного результата не достиг. Подскажите какой класс и параметры добавить в строку,

````
 <div class="fr-carousel-inner">
  <div class="fr-item fr-active"><a href="https://dtk.su/mycatalog?catalogId=8698"> <img src="//f.nodacdn.net/397681" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
  <div class="fr-item"><a href="https://dtk.su/mycatalog?catalogId=9005"> <img src="//f.nodacdn.net/397679" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
  <div class="fr-item"><a href="https://dtk.su/mycatalog?catalogId=8680"><img src="//f.nodacdn.net/397677" alt="" width="100%" /></a></div>
 </div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Голова после шоколадки сообразила и вспомнила про атрибуты!))

- Атрибуты
- **align** Определяет как рисунок будет выравниваться по краю и способ обтекания текстом.
- **alt** Альтернативный текст для изображения.
- **border** Толщина рамки вокруг изображения.
- **height** Высота изображения.
- **hspace** Горизонтальный отступ от изображения до окружающего контента.
- **ismap**  Говорит браузеру, что картинка является серверной картой-изображением.
- **longdesc** Указывает адрес документа, где содержится аннотация к картинке.
- **lowsrc** Адрес изображения низкого качества.
- **src** Путь к графическому файлу.
- **vspace** Вертикальный отступ от изображения до окружающего контента.
- **width**  Ширина изображения.
- **usemap** Ссылка на тег , содержащий координаты для клиентской карты-изображения.

Comment: Большая часть этих атрибутов считается устаревшими и в html5 не используется.